# Is there a way to automatically open a URL that I have stored in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am very new to SharePoint and the problem I have is as follows:

1. I have a list that stores names of managers along with a link. The
   link is actually the URL to an Excel Document from the SharePoint
   Document Library.
2. Each manager has a different link.
3. I have another SharePoint list in which I assign the manager to a person. After assigning manager, I want the link to be opened, and I want the contents of the Excel sheet to be automatically imported in a SharePoint list. I also want the list to have a custom name.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this slightly different approach :

- Instead of storing the link to an Excel file, make all the Excel files one excel file. Each row of this file should be a former single Excel file (with the former Excel rows now being the SharePoint columns), and the first column should now be the manager name.
- use the SharePoint feature that lets you import an Excel file straight into a SharePoint list. This Excel file is now hosted on SharePoint, and each row has a manager name as the first column.
- every time you assign a manager to a person, use a lookup from this person to the manager to get the corresponding row in the sharepoint list. Then finally display the targetted columns wherever you want (you didn't say what you do with the data from the excel file, how you display it or where you put it).